# elastic search with spring boot not work

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot

in spring boot project.

gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch')
    compile('io.searchbox:jest:2.0.3')
    runtime('net.java.dev.jna:jna')
}
```

config.yml:

```
spring:
  data:
    elasticsearch:
      cluster-nodes: 10.19.132.207:9300
      cluster-name: es
  elasticsearch:
    jest:
      uris: http://10.19.132.207:9200
      read-timeout: 10000
```

And my es config:

```
cluster.name: es
node.name: node-1
network.host: 0.0.0.0
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9200
```

when I want to save data to es. The console print:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{10.19.132.207}{10.19.132.207:9300}]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:326) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:223) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:55) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
```

And my es print log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received message from unsupported version: [2.0.0] minimal compatible version is: [5.0.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.messageReceived(TcpTransport.java:1323) ~[elasticsearch-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4MessageChannelHandler.channelRead(Netty4MessageChannelHandler.java:74) ~[transport-netty4-5.2.2.jar:5.2.2]
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, it appears that neither 'spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch' nor 'jest 2.0.3' support Elasticsearch 5. I'd try downgrading your Elasticsearch instance to 2.4.4 and see if that works.

Comment: Can I upgrade 'spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch' or 'jest 2.0.3' to support es 5?

Comment: You're certainly welcome to spend the time reading their source code and doing that.  Or you could use the Elasticsearch REST Client (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/_maven_repository.html) instead and save tons of time and code coupling.